# Multiple Columns in one table referencing back to one table get their values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table `table_One` which has Multiple `columns(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4.....)`  both references (`Contains PK values for Table_two`) to another table `Table_Two`. Is there any efficient way getting joining these two tables rather than joining Table_one back to table_Two Multiple Times.br/>

The Structure of the Two tables and the Desired Result Set is as follows. 
Table_One

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following solution ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22931)) reads the rows from the second table just one time:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
...
PRINT 'Test #1'
SELECT  *
FROM
(
    SELECT  ca.PrimaryKey, ca.[Type], y.ColumnA
    FROM    @Table1 x
    UNPIVOT( Value FOR [Type] IN ([Column1], [Column2]) ) ca
    INNER MERGE /*HASH*/ JOIN @Table2 y ON ca.Value = y.ID
) src
PIVOT( MAX(src.ColumnA) FOR src.[Type] IN ([Column1], [Column2]) ) pvt
PRINT 'End of Test #1'
```

Results:

```
Test #1
PrimaryKey Column1   Column2
---------- --------- -------
1          ALPHA     CHARLIE
2          BETA      DELTA
3          CHARLIE   ALPHA
4          DELTA     CHARLIE
5          ALPHA     DELTA
6          CHARLIE   ALPHA
7          ALPHA     DELTA
8          DELTA     CHARLIE

Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table '#65B6F546'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table '#61E66462'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

End of Test #1
```

Comment: Thank you Bogdan for your suggestion with a very detailed answer and explanation I will definitely give a go. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried aliasing your table2 table and joining it twice to Table_One like below?

```
SELECT
    t1.PrimaryKey,
    c1.ColumnA AS Column1,
    c2.ColumnA AS Column2
FROM Table_One t1
JOIN Table_two c1 ON t1.Column1 = c1.ID
JOIN Table_two c2 ON t1.Column2 = c2.ID;
```

Comment: Thank for your reply JRam :) G Mastros included some explanation as well in his answer, anyway thank for you help buddy.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Table_One.PrimaryKey,
       T2_Column1.ColumnA As Column1,
       T2_Column2.ColumnA As Column2
From   Table_One
       Inner Join Table_Two As T2_Column1
         On Table_One.Column1 = T2_Column1.ID
       Inner Join Table_Two As T2_Column2
         On Table_One.Column2 = T2_Column2.Id
```

Basically, you join to table 2 twice.  When you do this, you MUST alias at least one of them so that SQL doesn't get confused.  As a matter of practice, it's usually best to alias both of them so that when you read this code again in 6 months, it will be easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response I will try this tomorrow at work, Table one is a very big table with some 20 million records and I end up creating a UDF with Table_two's PK as a parameter returning ColumnA's Values. DO you reckon that should do the job as well as I am already joining to almost 13-15 different tables to get the required result set. This question was only a part of my whole query. Any suggestions please .

Comment: It is hard to say. I strongly suspect that the performance of this method will be better, but depending on the UDF you created, the performance of that may also be good.  If I had to guess, I would say that the performance of this method will be at least as good if not better (potentially a lot better).  Also consider that the performance will largely depend on the indexes you have on your table.

Comment: I doubt it if there are in indexes on this particular column since there are nearly 170 columns in this table, I havent really used this column this much as yet but I will check the execution plans with your solution and the way I am already doing it. lets see which one suits me most. anyway your help is much appreciated, Cheers pal :)

Comment: The indexes on table 1 wouldn't need to be too complicated, so it may be worth your while to give it a try.  Of course, I wouldn't do it in production, but if you can do it in a dev environment, that would be great.

Comment: Yes I will give it a go on dev server tomorrow. fingers crossed :)