# SQL Select two columns from one table translated by a column from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table IDs, first names, and last names. I also have a table of children and parents. I want to translate the children/parent table from int to nvarchar using the ID table. In this example, we have two people, Mark and Ray Smith. Ray is Mark's parent. Ray has no parent.

```
People_Table  
ID|First|Last  
--+-----+----  
0 |NULL|NULL  
10|Mark|Smith  
15|Ray |Smith  

Parent_Child_Table  
Child|Parent  
-----+------  
10   | 15  
15   | 0
```

I want to get

```
First|Last|First|Last  
-----+-----+----+-----  
Mark|Smith|Ray|Smith  
Ray|Smith|NULL|NULL
```

I've tried using INNER JOIN but that only gives me the name of the children, for example. Using two select statements gets me one list of all the people, but doesn't maintain the structure. Any ideas?

Sorry for the ugly editing (or lack thereof), this is my first time posting here, and I'm rushing. I hope it's not confusing.

Comment: I asked a very similar question a bit ago and got some very detailed answers from some sql gurus definitely worth looking at, have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436033/two-columns-in-one-table-referrencing-back-to-one-table-get-their-values/19437119?noredirect=1#19437119

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select p.first, p.last, c.first, c.last
from parent_child_table pc 
inner join people_table p on p.id = pc.parent
inner join people_table c on c.id = pc.child
```

Comment: Thanks @juergen d! I was trying:  
SELECT People_Table.First, People_Table.Last, People_Table.First, People_Table.Last  
FROM People_Table  
INNER JOIN Parent_Child_Table ON People_Table.First = Parent_Child_Table.First  
INNER JOIN Parent_Child_Table ON People_Table.Last = Parent_Child_Table.Last.

Comment: If you join the same table twice you have to alias them in order to distinguish them.

Comment: Okay, that does make sense. Another hang-up I had is: why are we querying from parent_child_table when the data we want is essentially from people_table?

Comment: It does not really matter which table you mention first in the query.